# Disable dragging group selection while keeping shift+click group selection in Fabric

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a way to disable group selection via dragging while keeping shift+click group selection? I'm aware of `canvas.selection = false;`, but that seems to disable both kinds of group selection. I looked through previous questions but couldn't find one that addressed this. Thanks for any suggestions!